# Congruences of weights of modular forms modulo primes

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

I'm trying to prove that for two modular forms $f$ and $g$ of weight $k$ and $k'$ respectively, that are congruent modulo a prime $\ell\ge 5$, their weights are congruent modulo $\ell-1$. This is what I have so far: if $f\equiv g\pmod\ell$ then  $f\left(\frac{az+b}{cz+d}\right)\equiv g\left(\frac{az+b}{cz+d}\right)\pmod\ell\implies (cz+d)^{k}f(z)=(cz+d)^{k'}g(z)\pmod\ell$. \So$(cz+d)^{k}\equiv (cz+d)^{k}\pmod\ell$. So $(cz+d)^{k-k'}\equiv 1\pmod\ell$.
If $c\equiv 0\pmod\ell$ then $d^{k-k'}\equiv 1\pmod\ell$ and by Fermat's little theorem $d^{k-k'}\equiv d^{\ell-1}\pmod\ell$. So $k-k'\equiv 0\pmod{\ell-1}\implies k\equiv k'\pmod{\ell-1}$

Is this the right way to go and if so is it possible to extend this for all $c$? Thank you.

Comment: Rather than $c \cong 0$, better to observe: if it is true for all $z$, it is true for $z=0$.  The only real concern is at $z=-d/c$, which is not actually a concern.  (Why?)

Comment: Because they are both holomorphic at infinity?

Comment: This is nonsense: what does it mean that the **complex number** $f(az + b / cz + d)$ satisfies a congruence modulo $\ell$? Congruences of modular forms are defined in terms of their Fourier coefficients; they have very little to do with the values $f(z)$ for $z$ in the upper half-plane.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Sorry yes I was hoping that it would be possible to prove it in terms of $z$ rather than $q$ but reading your answer I realised I was talking rubbish. Apologies I'm pretty new to this field. I'm guessing it's not possible to establish a bijection between the Fourier expansion and $f(z)$?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you read one of the papers of Serre where this result is proved?  The argument is not too difficult if you know some theory, but is not something you will be able to work out for yourself if all you know is the bare definition of a modular form.  (Serre's Antwerp article in LNM 350 proves it, and it might also be proved in his Bourbaki seminar "apres Swinnerton-Dyer".)

As David Loeffler commented, your current argument is nonsense.